# PHP Notice: Undefined index: status on line

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code :

```
if (isset($form['status']) && $form['status'] == 0)
    $status0 = ' selected';
elseif (isset($form['status']) && $form['status'] == 1)
    $status1 = ' selected';
```

HTML:

```
<option <?PHP echo $status0; ?>>YES</option>
```

Now, I see This Error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: status0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\cms.php on line 212
```

How Do i can fix This?!

Comment: You have to define it first `$status0 =null` at the top

Comment: It doesn't really matter what value in the MySQL database is. The error indicates that when the variable `$status0` is referenced, it has not yet been defined. (We conclude that the `if` condition did not evaluate to TRUE, and that `$status0` isn't defined anywhere else before line 212. The "fix" is to define the variable somewhere other than just following an `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP gave you the answer:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: status0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\cms.php on line 212
```

Declare your vars before the if statement: `$status0 = null;`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `$status0` is not defined, because it skips all your `if/elseif` blocks. You can fix it by assigning `$status0` to the default value before the clauses or add `else` clause and assign `$status0` in it.